# please need help with this question

Tags: graph-theory

can somebody help me with this question?

Suppose a social network contains a number of people, each of whom has
one of two “opinions” (e.g. a preference for Mac versus PC). Each person is
connected with a set of “friends”, some of the other people in the network.
You can choose any person in the network and let them see the opinions of
their friends, and if most of the friends have the same opinion, then the chosen
person will change their opinion to the one shared by the majority of their
friends. If there’s an equal split, you can choose their opinion. Assuming
the network is connected, can we always find a sequence of people so as to
ensure that they all end up with the same opinion?

Comment: What is meant by $"\ldots the\ network\ is\ connected\ldots"?$ What about $"\ldots they\ all\ldots"$? Who all?

Comment: i think  they all... mean the whole social network

Comment: This is not a question about probability. You should post this question with the tag "graph-theory".

Comment: thanks, i have changed the tag

Comment: Please consider adding a more appropiate title to this question. Also this is not a group theory question: group theory is a branch of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I actually understand the question, but if I do, my answer is a no:

```
A      B
 \    /
  A--B
 /    \
A      B
```

I can not see a way to change any opinions in this graph.

Even if you do not like the antisocial persons with one friend:

```
A------B
|\    /|
| A--B |
|/    \|
A------B
```

Fun fact: 'clique' has a meaning both for graphs and for human relations.

Comment: i have studies and researched further and found the question is from https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch19.pdf this book and this chapter. i need help understanding the term "a sequence of people ?" in the question

Comment: @anum the linked book chapter contains 4 occurrences of "sequence". 3 of them are actually "consequence" and the "real" one speaks about "sequence of changes" (footnote on page 569)

Comment: i have studies further now but i can see this i snot linked to that chapter